# Selecting the best subset of features in binary logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, conditional-probability, log-linear

I am using a binary logistic regression (a type of probabilistic statistical classification model, is used to predict a likelihood of belonging to a class (True, False)). I have 4 features and I want to know what is the best subset of using these features to reach the best result? should I try all of possible subset of these features? Is there any scientific solution for this purpose?
I don't have sufficient knowledge about this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your number of features is small, you can try all possible combinations.

In general, regularization is often used for feature selection:

http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html